# Google Map API V3 - ReferenceError: Google is not defined - script error in Windows 2008 R2 new machine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an html page that works in my local machine, perfectly and I have the same page in an old server, and it works too.

Now, we try to migrate to a new server and we have script errors.

Whenever i try to load the google maps html code i never get anything to display and i get the following error:

ReferenceError: google is not defined

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

    <style>
        .etiqueta {
            font-size: 9pt; 
            font-family: 'Microsoft Sans Serif';
        }

        .valor {
            width: 95%;
        }

    </style>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gmap;
        var myPano = null;
        var puntolatlon;
        var prmDir;
        var geocoder;
        var geoMarker;
        var prmLngX = null;
        var prmLatY = null;
        var prmYaw = null;
        var prmPitch = null;
        var prmZoom = null;
        var prmDir = null;

        var iconoFarmacia = {
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(8, 9),
            url: './iconos/iconoFarmacia.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(16, 16)
        };

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        function initialize() 
        {
            var mapOptions = 
            {
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                scaleControl: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: true,
                overviewMapControl: true,
                overviewMapControlOptions: { opened: true }
            };

            gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            //obtenemos los parametros que nos vienen en la URL
            URL = location.href;
            //longitud
            if ((URL).search('longitudX') != -1) { prmLngX = leeParametros('longitudX'); }

            //latitud
            if ((URL).search('latitudY') != -1) { prmLatY = leeParametros('latitudY'); }

            //yaw
            if ((URL).search('yaw') != -1) { prmYaw = leeParametros('yaw'); }

            //pitch
            if ((URL).search('pitch') != -1) { prmPitch = leeParametros('pitch'); }

            //zoom
            if ((URL).search('zoom') != -1) { prmZoom = leeParametros('zoom'); }

            //direccion
            if ((URL).search('direccion') != -1) 
            {
                prmDir = leeParametros('direccion');
                prmDir = unescape(prmDir);

                if (prmDir != "") {
                    document.getElementById('txtCalle').value = prmDir;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                //una direccion por defecto
                prmDir = 'Conselleria de sanidade, San Lazaro, 15703 Santiago de Compostela';
                document.getElementById('txtCalle').value = prmDir;
            }

            if ( (prmLngX == null || prmLatY == null) && prmDir !=null )
            {
                // si no tenemos coordenadas obtenemos a partir de la direccion que viene en el parametro
                if (geocoder) 
                {
                    geocoder.geocode(
                        {
                            'address': prmDir, 
                            region: 'ES' 
                        },
                        function(results, status) 
                        {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                            {   var locResultado = results[0].geometry.location;
                                gmap.setCenter(locResultado);
                                gmap.setZoom(15);
                                addResultadoAMapa(locResultado);
                                inicializarTrasResultado(locResultado);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                alert(prmDir + ": dirección no encontrada: " + status);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            else if (prmLngX != null && prmLatY != null)
            {
                var puntoCoord = new google.maps.LatLng(prmLatY, prmLngX);
                gmap.setCenter(puntoCoord);
                gmap.setZoom(15);

                if (prmYaw == null || prmPitch == null || prmZoom == null) 
                {  //buscamos solo por coordenadas
                    addResultadoAMapa(puntoCoord);
                }
                else 
                {   //buscamos coordenas y yaw, pitch y zoom --> por todo
                    addResultadoAMapa(puntoCoord, prmYaw, prmPitch, prmZoom);
                }

                inicializarTrasResultado(puntoCoord);
            }
            else 
            {
                alert("Parámetros de búsqueda incompletos");
            }            
        }


        function inicializarTrasResultado(puntoCoord) 
        {
            if (geoMarker) geoMarker.setMap(null);

            //ponemos una marca encima de las coordenadas en el mapa
            geoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: gmap,
                position: puntoCoord,
                icon: iconoFarmacia
            });

            //var streetViewLayer = new google.maps.StreetViewCoverageLayer();
            //streetViewLayer.setMap(gmap);
        }


        function addResultadoAMapaGenerico(panoramaOptions, zoomAux) 
        {
            myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("streetviewpanoramadiv"), panoramaOptions);
            gmap.setStreetView(myPano);
            myPano.setVisible(true);

            var stvService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
            stvService.getPanoramaByLocation(myPano.getPosition(), 50, disponibilidadStreetview);

            document.getElementById("txtLong").value = redond(myPano.getPosition().lng(), 6);
            document.getElementById("txtLat").value = redond(myPano.getPosition().lat(), 6);
            document.getElementById("txtZoom").value = redond(zoomAux, 0);
            document.getElementById("txtYaw").value = redond(myPano.getPov().heading, 6);
            document.getElementById("txtPitch").value = redond(myPano.getPov().pitch, 6);

            google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, "error", handleNoFlash);
            google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, "pov_changed", onPovChange);
            google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, "initialized", onNewLocation);
            google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, 'position_changed', onPositionChanged);
            google.maps.event.addListener(gmap.getStreetView(), 'visible_changed', onVisibilityChanged);
        }


        function addResultadoAMapa(puntoLatLon) 
        {
            var yaw = null;
            var pitch = null;
            var punto = puntoLatLon;

            var panoramaOptions = 
            {
                position: puntoLatLon,
                pov: {
                    heading: yaw,
                    pitch: pitch
                }
            };

            addResultadoAMapaGenerico(panoramaOptions, myPano.getZoom());
        }


        function addResultadoAMapa(puntolatlon, yaw, pitch, zoom) 
        {
            if (isNaN(yaw)) { yaw = 0; }
            if (isNaN(pitch)) { pitch = 0; }
            if (isNaN(zoom)) { zoom = 0; }

            var yawAux = yaw;
            var pitchAux = pitch;
            var zoomAux = zoom;
            var punto = puntolatlon;

            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: puntolatlon,
                pov: {
                    heading: redond(yawAux, 6),
                    pitch: redond(pitchAux, 6),
                    zoom: redond(zoomAux, 6)
                }
            };

            addResultadoAMapaGenerico(panoramaOptions, zoomAux);
        }


        function disponibilidadStreetview(result, status) 
        {
            if (status != google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) 
            {
                document.getElementById("txtError").value = " 'Streetview' no disponible en la ubicación.";
                document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = 580 + 'px';
                document.getElementById("streetviewpanoramadiv").style.height = 0 + 'px';
            }
        }


        function redond(num, ndec) {
            var fact = Math.pow(10, ndec);

            /* Se desplaza el punto decimal ndec posiciones, 
            se redondea el numero y se vuelve a colocar 
            el punto decimal en su sitio. */
            return Math.round(num * fact) / fact;
        }

        function handleNoFlash(errorCode) {
            document.getElementById("txtError").value = " 'Streetview' no disponible en la ubicación.";
            //mostramos el mapa mas grande ya que no hay streetview
            document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = 580 + 'px';
            document.getElementById("streetviewpanoramadiv").style.height = 0 + 'px';
        }

        function onPovChange() {
            document.getElementById("txtZoom").value = redond(myPano.getZoom(), 0);
            document.getElementById("txtYaw").value = redond(myPano.getPov().heading, 6);
            document.getElementById("txtPitch").value = redond(myPano.getPov().pitch, 6);
        }

        function onNewLocation(point) {
            //para que funcione correctamente debo intercambiar los valores
            document.getElementById("txtLong").value = redond(point.lng(), 6);
            document.getElementById("txtLat").value = redond(point.lat(), 6);
        }

        function onPositionChanged() {
            //para que funcione correctamente debo intercambiar los valores
            document.getElementById("txtLong").value = redond(myPano.getPosition().lng(), 6);
            document.getElementById("txtLat").value = redond(myPano.getPosition().lat(), 6);
            var stvService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
            stvService.getPanoramaByLocation(myPano.getPosition(), 50, disponibilidadStreetview);
        }

        function onVisibilityChanged() 
        {
            if (this.getVisible() == false) 
            {
                document.getElementById("txtError").value = " 'Streetview' no disponible en la ubicación.";
                document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = 580 + 'px';
                document.getElementById("streetviewpanoramadiv").style.height = 0 + 'px';

                if (geoMarker) 
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtLong").value = redond(geoMarker.getPosition().lng(), 6);
                    document.getElementById("txtLat").value = redond(geoMarker.getPosition().lat(), 6);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                document.getElementById("txtError").value = "";
                document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.height = 296 + 'px';
                document.getElementById("streetviewpanoramadiv").style.height = 288 + 'px';
            }
        }


        function hasErrorOccurred(error) 
        {
            if (error) 
            {
                alert("Error " + error.code + ": " + (error.message || (error.details && error.details.join(" ")) || "Unknown error"));
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //funcion que lee los parametros de la URL
        function leeParametros(name) 
        {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
            var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);

            if (results == null)
                return "";
            else
            //necesario la funcion unescape porque algunos navegadores pintan los espacios como %20
                return unescape(results[1]);
        }
    </script> 

 </head>

 <body bgcolor="lightgrey">
   <form id="form1" runat="server" action="#">

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 296px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <br />

    <div id="streetviewpanoramadiv" style="height: 288px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <br /> 

    <fieldset style="width: 824px" align="center">
        <legend class="etiqueta">Datos Localización</legend> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtLong" ID="lblLon" class="etiqueta">Lon. (X):</label></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"><input type="text" ID="txtLong" class="valor" disabled /></td>

                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtLat" ID="lblLat" class="etiqueta">Lat. (Y):</label></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"><input type="text" ID="txtLat" class="valor" disabled /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtYaw" ID="lblYaw" class="etiqueta">Yaw:</label></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"><input type="text" ID="txtYaw" class="valor" disabled /></td>

                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtPitch" ID="lblYaw" class="etiqueta">Pitch:</label></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"><input type="text" ID="txtPitch" class="valor" disabled /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtZoom" ID="lblZoom" class="etiqueta">Zoom:</label></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"><input type="text" ID="txtZoom" class="valor" disabled /></td>

                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtError" ID="lblError" class="etiqueta">Descripción:</label></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"><input type="text" ID="txtError" class="valor" disabled /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 95px"><label for="txtCalle" ID="lblCalle" class="etiqueta">Ubicación:</label></td>
                <td colspan="3" ><input type="text" ID="txtCalle"  disabled style="width: 706px; text-transform :uppercase"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 95px"></td>
                <td style="width: 310px"></td>
                <td style="width: 90px"></td>
                <td style="width: 310px" align="right"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Somebody understand what is happening? Thanks, This is my first post in stackoverflow. 
We have IE9 in the new machine. My new server is Windows 2008 R2 with SO in 64bits and the old was Windows 2003 with 32 bits. 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you give a link to the page on the "new server"?

Comment: Is your new server blocking the javascript API code?

Comment: Sorry, this is a private server, only can use a determinate number of users, and this page is embedded in an internal application. No, the server is not blocking javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library

```
<script src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=drawing&dummy=.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, We have resolved the problem. 
It was a configuration problem wits security restrictions in server.
We change protocol https to http and we enable connections to *.gstatic.com and *.googleapis.com in server. 
The application is working now. 
Thank you for your help.